# Permission denied error message

Tags: bash, permission-denied

Can't execute a C-program I wrote although I have read, write and execute permissions for it.

Getting the following error message:

```
 -bash: ./program_name: Permission denied
```

What is going on here? Anybody has a clue?

UPDATE: I did not have execution permission for the binary file ... I have now changed the user rights for the binary file:
Here's the result of the command ls -l program_name:

```
-rwxr--r--@ 1 my_username  staff  2284 Jan 14 21:26 program_name
```

I now get the following error message when trying to run the file:           -

```
bash:./program_name: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: To close voters: I don't think this belongs on Super user since this has to do with compiling his own program w/ permissions. Not, for example, permission on a downloaded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet that you don't, in fact, have execute permission for it.

Check the permissions with:

`ls -l ./program_name`

Update your question with the output so we/I can cross check your conclusion.

*Update*: The output appears that you have execute permission on the source file (`.c` gives me that impression).  This will not work.

You need to compile C programs (usually with gcc on Linux, xcode<sup>1</sup> on Mac). If you did and everything is successful, you get a new file. Usually, without an extension. That is the executable and that is what needs the permissions.

So, assuming the executable is `program_name` without `.c` give it a try again.

<sup>1</sup> I think XCode uses GCC too

Comment: I inserted the result of the command "ls -l program_name.c " in my post ... As far as I can see, I have all rights